# Does adding new sorts to propositional logic with quantification keep the logic second-order?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, second-order-logic

Suppose we add propositional quantifiers in the language of propositional logic. So, for example, we can write $\forall\!p\,(p\lor\neg p)$ to express the proposition that every proposition is either true or false. This, I take it, is a special case of second-order logic. Now suppose that due to some (say, philosophical) reasons we want to distinguish between the two kinds of propositions, and that we want to extend/revise our formal system as well, in a way that captures two kinds of propositions. What comes to my mind is to add a new *sort* to the language, so we have two sorts of propositions.

For example, let $\langle\rangle\!/\!1$ and $\langle\rangle\!/\!2$ stand for our two sorts of propositions. Suppose also we superindex variables with these symbols to indicate their sorts (e.g., $p^{\langle\rangle\!/\!1}$ is a sort-${\langle\rangle\!/\!1}$ variable). We revise our primary logic in a way that these sorts are accommodated. For instance, we allow Boolean connectives to now take arguments from each sort, and in our term-formation rules we say that, e.g., both $\forall p^{\langle\rangle\!/\!1}\phi$ and $\forall p^{\langle\rangle\!/\!2}\phi$ are well-formed formulas whenever $\phi$ is.

Now my question is this: *Would this sortifying the space of propositions keep things second-order?* What does 'order' in sorted languages even mean?

Comment: No, quantifying over propositions doesn't give you 2nd order logic at all: it has nothing to do with 2nd order logic! It isn't even 1st order logic. It's just propositional logic, with more expressive power. It seems that your 2 sorts of propositions require no additional axioms, syntactic constraints or inference rules: the 2 kinds of variables are interchangeable. This imposes no additional requirements on models.
Re notation: the symbols you chose to indicate the two sorts of propositions are awful: they look just like each other and both look like nothing, all detail no clear glyph.

Comment: Why not construe propositional quantification as an instance of second-order quantification?! In second-order logic, we quantify over n-ary predicates. We can just consider propositions as nullary predicates. In other words, just like in predicate logic we consider propositions as nullary predicates (hence propositional logic is a fragment of predicate logic), so can we understand the propositional quantifiers as the special case of second-order quantifiers binding nullary predicate variables (hence proportional quantification is a special case of second-order quantification).

Comment: Re my notation, some texts on relational type theory use $\langle\rangle$ for propositional types (special case of n-ary relational types $\langle t_1,...,t_n\rangle$, where $n=0$). I find my notation close to that. Btw I forgot to mention that my two sorts both have their own axioms that distinguishes them.

Comment: You certainly can construe quantified boolean logic as a special case of second order logic where the only predicates are nullary (i.e., take no arguments). But why would you want to introduce two different sorts of propositions? Many-sorted languages have different sorts for individuals (e.g., different sorts for the scalars and vectors in a language for vector spaces). Second-order languages are ones that allow you to quantify over predicates. HIgher-order languages allow predicates to take predicates as arguments (and so on ). "Order" and "sort" are independent ideas.

Comment: I want to somehow maintain the intuition that the whole quantification-over-sorted-propositions is *still* happening at the level of the second-order logic. In other words, I thought doing what I'm trying to do keeps things second-order, but for different *sorts* of second-order variables instead of one. This can matter for philosophical reasons: some philosophers don't like full-on higher-order logic but nevertheless feel comfortable with propositional quantification. By trying to "keep things second-order" I'm trying to avoid more sophisticated higher-order quantification into my system.

Comment: Consider this example that led me to me question. We can translate first-order modal logic into a two-sorted predicate logic (see e.g., Brauner and Ghilardi's "First-Order Modal Logic" in the *Handbook of Modal Logic*). The idea is to treat 'worlds' as a second sort, along with the first sort which is the sort of individuals. Then quantifications over both worlds and individuals is *still* considered as *first order*. I thought the same idea may apply to my case: allowing the same old (propositional) quantifier to range over the new sorts may indicate that we're still doing second-order logic.

Comment: I see. But in introducing two sorts of propositional variable you are introducing two sorts of proposition. Which sort of proposition is the right one for the propositions that are the theorems of your system? Or do you have two sorts of theorems as well? There may well be some promise in your idea, but perhaps it would be clearer to avoid using the term "sort". Maybe you could talk about different "kinds" of propositions (cf. logics like Martin-Löf type theory that have different kinds of judgment).

Comment: Each sort has its own theorems (e.g., Universal Instantiation), and some theorems related them to each other. I'm definitely going to look up Martin-Löf type theory